# Problemas al dar estilos CSS a botones de un editor de contenido

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Me estoy iniciando en el mundo de *CSS* y *jquery* y me he propuesto crear una barra de opciones de editor de texto parecida a esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para iniciar hice este código *HTML* y *CSS*, para ir generando algunos elementos a mi barra de opciones de editor de texto, quería aplicar estilos para que se parezca lo más posible al estilo de la imagen, pero el resultado final es todo lo contrario, sobre todo en las opciones del segundo div; las del primer div están alineadas una al lado de la otra, pero las opciones del segundo div no.

¿Qué estilos *CSS* se podrían aplicar para darle una apariencia similar a la imagen mostrada más arriba?

```css
 ul{
   list-style: none; 
   padding-left: 5px; 
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   }

 #sizes{
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 92px; 
   padding-top: 0px;
   }

 #weightL {
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 13%;
   }

 #italics{
   display: inline-block; width: 15%;
   }

 #colorsPick{
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 30%;
   }

 #family-font{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
                                           
 input[type=checkbox]{
   display:none;
   }

 input[type=checkbox] + label.btn{
   padding: 5px 10px;
   margin: 5px 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 700;
   outline: none;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   transition: all 0.3s;
   background: rgb(239, 237, 238);
   color: black;
   box-shadow: 0 6px rgba(214, 209, 210);;
   -webkit-transition: none;
   -moz-transition: none;
   transition: none;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   }

 input[type=checkbox] + label.btn:hover{
   box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(214, 209, 210);
   top: 2px;
   }

 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.btn{
   box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(214, 209, 210);
   top: 6px;
   }
```

```html
<div id="first-options">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnTitle"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="display: inline-block;"></i> Big Text</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubtitle"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="display: inline-block;"></i> Small Text</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnAddText"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="display: inline-block;"></i> Text Box</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnImg"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="display: inline-block;"></i> Image</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnLink"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="display: inline-block;"></i> Link</button>
</div>
<div id="myOptionBar">
    <ul>
       <li id="sizes">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <label style="display: inline-block; width: 34px;">Size </label>
            <input style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 12px; padding-top: 0px;width: 54px;" type="number" id="font-size" min="14" max="100" value="34" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </li>
       <li id="weightL">
           <div style="display: block;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="font-weight">
                <label for="font-weight-title" class="btn"><b>Bold</b></label>
           </div></li>
       <li id="italics">
           <div style="display: block;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="font-style-title">
                <label for="font-style" class="btn"><i>Italic</i></label>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li id="colorsPick">
           <div style="display: block;">
                <!-- Color Picker -->
                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="input-group my-colorpicker2" id="color-box">
                          <input type="color" id="color-title" value="#000002" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 21px;">
                              <div class="input-group-append">
                                   <span class="input-group-text" style="padding-bottom: 6.5px; padding-top: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></span>
                               </div>
                     </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
                </div>
           <!-- /.form group -->
           </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="family-font">
         <label style="display: inline-block;">Fonts: </label>
         <select class="form-control" id="font-family" style="display: inline-block; width: 80%;">
            <option value="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Arial Helvetica</option>
            <option value="‘Arial Black’, Gadget, sans-serif">Arial Black Gadget</option>
            <option value="‘Bookman Old Style’, serif">Bookman Old Style</option>
            <option value="Garamond, serif">Garamond</option>
            <option value="Georgia, serif">Georgia</option>
            <option value="‘Comic Sans MS’, cursive">Comic Sans MS cursive</option>
            <option value="Courier, monospace">Courier monospace</option>
            <option value="‘Courier New’, Courier, monospace">Courier New Courier monospace</option>
            <option value="Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif">Impact Charcoal</option>
            <option value="‘Lucida Console’, Monaco, monospace">Lucida Console Monaco monospace</option>
            <option value="‘Lucida Sans Unicode’, ‘Lucida Grande’, sans-serif">Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
            <option value="‘MS Sans Serif’, Geneva, sans-serif">MS Sans Serif Geneva</option>
            <option value="‘MS Serif’, ‘New York’, sans-serif">MS Serif New York</option>
            <option value="‘Palatino Linotype’, ‘Book Antiqua’, Palatino, serif">Palatino Linotype</option>
            <option value="Symbol, sans-serif"> Symbol, sans-serif</option>
            <option value="Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif"> Tahoma Geneva</option>
            <option value="‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value="‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif">Trebuchet MS Helvetica</option>
            <option value="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">Verdana Geneva</option>
            <option value="Webdings, sans-serif">Webdings</option>
            <option value="Wingdings, ‘Zapf Dingbats’, sans-serif">Wingdings Zapf Dingbats</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Marcos, no me queda claro a que te refieres con "primer div" y "segundo div". A no ser que te refieras al desplegable de las fuentes. De todas formas, en el código que has añadido no veo parecido a la imagen original, tal y como dices en la pregunta. Por favor, revisa el código para ver si lo que has puesto se asemeja a tus problemas actuales.

Comment: para empezar, si recién estas iniciando en este tema lo que hiciste esta muy bien, por un lado te podría recomendar que para parecerte mas a lo que nos mostraste, podrias comenzar a reemplazar las etiquetas de texto por iconos. Es decir, en vez de utilizar "bold" o "italic" uses iconos, lo cual volverá el resultado mucho mas elegante y parecido a lo que nos mostraste.

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo usar un poco menos de Style inline, y pasarlo todo a tu pagina de estilos, ya que la veo bien ordenada. Lo mismo de los iconos te recomiendo que los uses para la sección donde dice "big text" "small text" "text box" y los demás.

Ademas, te recomendaria que retoques el estilo del selector de fuente para que sea mas pequeño.

Comment: Por ultimo, si queres que se parezca aun mas a lo que nos mostraste primero, podrias agregar unos bordes redondeados, sombreados y con otros detalles con CSS, a TODO el "editor". No se si se entiende esto ultimo, me refiero a que a todo el editor de texto que creaste, le apliques un borde al rededor, con un estilo que te agrade. Cualquier cosa pregunta! Saludos y ojala te vaya bien con tu proyecto!

Comment: Hola @SantiagoHernanAguirrePerez Gracias por estas increibles sugerencias, me han ayudado. He seguido tus sugerencias, he investigado y encontrado muchas reglas CSS que me han servido para lograr mejorar el estilo de todas esas opciones y le he aplicado border al editor como dices, ahora se ve mucho mejor.

Comment: Hola @MarcosSchmell , si has encontrado una solución a tu problema sería bueno que añadieras una respuesta indicando cómo la has resuelto y la puedes aceptar también. De esta manera, otras personas que acaben en tu pregunta podrán ver cómo has resuelto tu problema. Un saludo ;)